# Angularjs directive: Image sequence flickers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am trying to create an angularjs directive of an image sequence to display it as a video.

There are 28 images for each sequence and there is some random subsequence
that i want to run as a video. 
Somehow it is running but it flickers when it changes the images.

http://jsfiddle.net/5n3jcsv6/3/

the list of subsequences is declared in the testing controller

```
$scope.sequences = [12,1];
```

and also the iteration starts

```
$scope.nextseq = function(){
      for(var i = $scope.thisequenceidx; i < $scope.sequences.length; i++)
...
```

I'm using setInterval() for animating in this case the 2 sequences, not so clever way cause it is kinda supposing some duration to 4500 ms for each animation and not waiting for each to finish; while the sequence is handled with some specific timeout based on the index.

Can someone help me with the image flickering?

Comment: Are you preloading the images? Or to put it another way, once every image is shown, does it still flicker?

Comment: yes even if the images are cached it still does the same thing, you can see it in the fiddle